# Where are apache rewrite rules if there is no .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have adopted a website that runs on a virtual machine with apache2 and uses Cloudflare.

It is a generic WordPress installation, and runs just fine. I noticed however, that there was no `.htaccess` file for the site. The `apache2.conf` file shows:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
```

If I change this to `AllowOverride All` and create a `.htaccess`, it reads it just fine. To my knowledge though, WordPress requires certain rewrite rules to be active in order for it to function. Since the site is functioning just fine without the `.htaccess` file, where would these rewrite rules be located? I was thinking they were setup in Cloudflare, however I don't see any page/transform rules in there.

When I run `apachectl -M` to see a list of enabled modules, `mod_rewrite` does **not** show up either.

Comment: ".htaccess" style files, usually called "distributed configuration files" are just a last option. Usually the preferred way to implement such rules is the actual http server's configuration. That is much more efficient and also more secure than ".htaccess" files. Plus you create less chaos since you don't have to consider a potential zoo of such files in your file system.

Comment: If there really is no rewriting module loaded into that http server then it might also be that the apache http server is only used as a frontend server. Kind of a proxy between clients and the actual application server, which might be a lightty or a nginx server. That would be a highly exotic setup, but very well possible.

Comment: WordPress doesn't necessarily _need_ any rewriting rules - it depends whether you are using "pretty permalinks". Are you using "pretty permalinks"? Or does `index.php` appear in the URL? `<Directory /var/www/>` - The site itself (often a `<VirtualHost>`) would be defined in a subdirectory. Where is the site config? What is the `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: You're right, I failed to even look at how the links were showing up. This is a fresh fresh site on a custom server, so the URLs were showing `index.php` in them, and the rewrite module hadn't been enabled yet. All is working now properly after switching the permalink structure and enabling the rewrite module.

Comment: I voted to close this question because you indicate that you resolved the problem without receiving any answers. If you still need answers, please [edit] the question to indicate that the issue is not fully resolved. If the solution you found would be useful to others, please answer your own question by pressing the "Answer Your Question" button.